# Forced zip file for download is corruption on unzip

Tags: php, zip

I have a zip file. I have made a script to force it getting download

But the issue is that, when I unzip the saved zipped file, I get error stating either the file is corrupt or.

Here's my script

```
$itsfile = $folder.'.zip';

$file_name = basename($itsfile);

header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($itsfile));

readfile($itsfile);
exit;
```

But still, when I am unzipping the saved file, I am getting error.

```
!   D:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\file.zip: The archive is either in unknown format or damaged
```

### Edit

The zip file contains a folder called image with images inside it, and a csv file having some data. Does that information help anyway?

[image]

Comment: You need a little more info than "file is corrupt". Else make a binary diff.

Comment: First step: Is the downloaded file the exact same size (in bytes) as the original? (Windows says `1 KB` in your screenshot, so I suspect it is not.)

Comment: yes, that the problem i am getting.. actualy the zip file is getting dynamicaly created in the project folder. Then i am forcing the file to get download. the zip file getting created in project folder is working fine when i am trying to unzip the file.... but when i am forcing it to download and save in another location, then i am geting the error while unzipping the forced file

Comment: And, can't be bothered to look into the downloaded ZIP with a hexeditor or something?

Comment: dont know how to do that @mario